# Registration script tips

Tags: php, sql, registration

Register.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));    
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
$passwd = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['passwd']));

if (empty($username)) {
   die ('You need to enter a username.');
}...... else insert



}

?>
```

Is it good to use mysql_real_escape_string and trim like this? Or is a btter way to make sure no one can register blank usernames etc

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see no problems with that code.  Typically I would first trim(), then perform any validation required, and then mysql_escape() (saving the mysql_escape till the last possible moment.  If the only validation you are going to do is to check for empty strings then I see no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

**The "yes" part**

It's good to sanitize user input for SQL Injection.  And since it won't affect an empty string, you won't generate any false positives or other side effects with this method.

**The "no" part**

Technically speaking, you don't want to filter data too early.  I would trim first, check value, and THEN escape it for a query when you know the data is valid.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
  $username = trim( $_POST['username'] );

  if ( '' == $username )
  {
    die ( 'You need to enter a username.' );
  } else {
    mysql_query( sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO table (username) VALUES('%s')"
      , mysql_real_escape_string( $username )
    ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *strlen()* instead of *empty()* when  you check for a 0 length string, with the *empty* function ...

> The following things are considered to
>   be empty:
>
> ```
> * "" (an empty string)
> * 0 (0 as an integer)
> * "0" (0 as a string)
> * NULL
> * FALSE
> * array() (an empty array)
> * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

As you can see, not all these values are an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use both. I also recommend using [filter_var](http://php.net/filter) because it will sanitize data as well. There are also many other things to consider.

- Usernames should probably only be letters and numbers
- Emails should be in the proper format
- You should trim() everything